# How to use document.querySelectorAll() into jQuery for performance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-ui

I have read that there can be significant performance improvements by switching over to `document.querySelectorAll()` rather than using jQuery's native selector.

Would doing the following have any performance benefit in jQuery, for instances involving thousands of elements and nested loops, etc.

```
//using querySelectorAll

elems = document.querySelectorAll('.element');
$(elems).addClass("className");
```

As opposed to doing:

```
//traditional jQuery
elems = $(".element");
$(items).addClass("className");
```

If not, what is a way that we can incorporate `document.querySelectorAll` into jQuery?

Comment: The only problem is, `querySelectorAll` does not return a collection of jQuery objects, and therefore, has no `.addClass()` method. `Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelectorAll(...).addClass is not a function`... So you have to write that yourself as well. At the end of the day, it's up to you to go easy mode with jQuery and its handy methods, or hardcore performance mode and get rid of jQuery entirely.

Comment: Your first code would have to translate to `document.querySelectorAll('.element').forEach(ele => ele.classList.add('className'))`

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks but doesn't answer the question unfortunately. Is there a way to use `document.querySelectorAll()` as the jQuery selector itself, is what I am asking. I am able to convert jQuery into Vanilla JS, but there are thousands of lines of code so it isn't feasible.

Comment: The answer was already given, the answer is no

Comment: @JeremyThille `$(elems)` converts it to a jQuery object, which does have `.addClass()`.

Comment: @trippyyyreddd In your second snippet, `$(items)` should be `elems` (no `$()` needed, since it's already a jQuery object).

Comment: @Barmar Indeed, you're right. But then, what's the point of using `querySelectorAll` for performance, then waste time transforming the result into jQuery objects, I wonder...

Comment: @JeremyThille For the convenience of using methods like `.addClass()` and `.hide()`, instead of having to write loops and conditionals.

Comment: That's exactly my point. jQuery is _convenient_. If OP wants to go full performance, they need to drop jQuery entirely, but they will lose all the handy methods as well.

Comment: @JeremyThille Show me where I said I would like to go "full performance". The aim of the question was to see if I could improve performance of the jQuery selector. I didn't say I would like to convert jQuery to purely Vanilla JS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it should work. `$(elems)` will create a jQuery collection object from the `NodeList`, and then you can use jQuery methods on it.

However, I don't think there will be as much benefit as you expect. jQuery already calls `querySelectorAll()` when feasible. There may be a small amount of overhead in determining whether QSA can be used for a given selector. But jQuery caches the result of this, so the overhead is mitigated if you use a selector frequently.